# Customizing ChatList UI design @ Homescreen

Tags: android, mesibo

In Mesibo Chat android application, I need to customize view of chat list appears at home screen. Need to customize profile image shape and design.
Please suggest me on how to customize mesibo ui?

Mesibo api, android:

```
public class UIManager {
    public static void launchStartupActivity(Context context, boolean skipTour) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StartUpActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(StartUpActivity.SKIPTOUR, skipTour);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
...
}
```

I need the way how to override chat list design.

Answer (score 0):

A recommended way is to use Mesibo `Fragment` instead of  `Activity`.

Refer https://mesibo.com/documentation/ui-modules/

Comment: I have created fragments and separate layouts also. But, I am recieving empty array for UserList in MesiboUserListFragment. Could you please suggest me how to get the data from to fill the adapter.

Comment: @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(getArguments() != null){
        Log.d(TAG, getArguments().toString());
        mUserList = MesiboUserListFragment.mMemberProfiles; <= How to fetch user list here ???

    }
}